# Using JQuery in a content script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use JQuery in my content script but The chrome console spits this out "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ". I can successfully use JQuery in my background script so I'm not exactly sure whats up.

Here's the  manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "Something",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "SOmething",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js", "jquery.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "favicon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "declarativeContent",
        "http://localhost/",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://localhost/",
        "https://*/*",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "48": "icon-48p.png"
    },

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": ["content.js", "jquery.js"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["button.PNG", "jquery.js"],
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Here's the content script:

```
var btn = document.createElement("input");
btn.id = "btn";
btn.type = "image";
btn.setAttribute("src", chrome.extension.getURL("button.PNG"));
btn.onclick = function() {
    alert("Currently under development");
};
btn.className = "";


if (window.location.href.indexOf("mysite") > -1) {
    $('#pageContainer').append('<ol><li>CATS</li><ol>'); //Fails here

}


if (window.location.href.indexOf("myother") > -1) {
    document.getElementById("maindiv").appendChild(btn); //works
}
```

Edit: JQuery is in the project and it does work in background.js. The question is how do I get it working within my content script? I've specified in the manifest that I want jquery injected along with content.js.

Comment: Can you post something that tells us the order in which the scripts are loaded? In which context do you use this snipplet?

Comment: I've added more let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Did you load JQuery before on your site?

Comment: Nope The site doesn't have JQuery.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that you cannot use JQuery and you're not wondering why it is not working without it, right?

Comment: No my question is why is JQuery working in background.js and not in my content script (content.js). I've edited my question. Maybe it will be more clear. Thanks

Comment: I wonder about this '"persistent": true'. May this cache the loaded scripts? Have you ever tried switching the order in your content scripts: `"js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]`

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make jQuery the first content script listed in the`content_scripts -> js` array. Like:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
}],
```

Your content script is trying to access jquery before it's loaded. The way your manifest is set up now, jQuery still should be loaded however. To verify this, type something like `window.jQuery` into the console on the content script page and make sure that it is defined.

Comment: I'm facing this issue even with them in the right order: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

As berrberr pointed out, you have to load jquery before your content.js script as follows

```
"js": ["jquery.js","content.js"]
```

or you can achieve the same in Pure JS using appendChild().

Also a note: If you are manipulating DOM elements, try injecting your script at `document_end`